# Using factor loadings of PCA to compute component values in R

Tags: r, pca, evaluate

I'm very new to statistical analysis. I'm using a questionnaire I found in a paper to evaluate my study. The questionnaire comes with factor loadings for each item on different components, but I'm asking myself how to use those loadings with my dataset. The values of the answers range from 1 to 6 and I already inverted negative loadings.
So here is the loading matrix:
[image]

I already did the questionnaire with the items (sp4, sp5, ...) as columns and the answers as rows.

So my questions: How can I use those loadings to compute the components 1-3? The answers of the items range from "I do not agree" to "I totally agree", is the calculation different with bipolar answers (e.g. "enjoyable" (1) and "unpleasant" (6))?

Thanks already and best wishes! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is a common factor analysis which sets the communalities to 1 rather than a true PCA - generally PCA results aren't rotated.  If it is a true PCA, then the scores are just the matrix of variables multiplied by the matrix of component loadings.  PCA uses a singular value decomposition to find:

[image]

with the idea that the ortho-normal variance maximizing components UD = XV.  That is, the right singular vectors (aka loadings) are the coefficients that map the variables onto the components.  Here's an example in R:

```r
library(psych)
G <- scale(Garcia)
p1 <- princomp(G)
c1 <- G %*% p1$loadings
## correlation between internally computed components
## and components created by multiplying variables by loadings
diag(cor(c1, p1$scores))
# Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 
#      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

With factor analysis, the model is different so the solution to find the scores is a bit different.  Here, regression-based scores are often computed with

[image]

Where Rxx is the correlation matrix among the factors, Ryy is the correlation matrix among the variables, Lambda is the matrix of factor loadings and Y is the matrix of observed variables.  Here's an example in R:

```r
mle3 <- fa(G,3,fm="minres" ,rotate="oblimin", SMC=FALSE)  #principal axis 
Rxx <- mle3$Phi
Ryy <- cor(G)
lambda <- mle3$loadings
s1 <- G %*% t(Rxx %*% t(lambda) %*% solve(Ryy))
## correlation between internally computed factor scores
## and scores created with the equation above. 
diag(cor(s1, mle3$scores))
# MR1 MR3 MR2 
#   1   1   1
```

So, the method you used will govern how you map the variables onto the components. If you're looking for a good reference, I've found Stanley Mulaik's [*Foundations of Factor Analysis*](https://www.routledge.com/Foundations-of-Factor-Analysis/Mulaik/p/book/9781420099614) to be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is the scale of the variables necessary as the results seam to be very random (instead of not normalizing the variables)?

Comment: The `scale()` function is standardizing them - so they have mean 0 and variance of 1.  The factor analysis routine uses internally standardizes the variables by decomposing the correlation rather than the covariance matrix.  So, when you make the scores, you need to use standardized variables.